# Windows Local app working fine but the app in the windows store has some issues

Tags: uwp

I completed a xamarin forms application and upload the windows app to windows store.

Then I install it on a windows device, but some features are not working on it(Picture uploading, circle image etc). The local app is working fine, but the app in the windows store has some issues. Is anybody have the same experience?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running local in Release Mode?

Comment: Try installing release version in your device before publishing to store instead of debug mode, if every thing looks fine then publish it in the store

Comment: I will install the release mode and update here

Comment: @AbsoluteSith The issues are there with the release mode

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Why happening like this, in debug mode everything was working fine.

Comment: @SreejithSree: There are times when some of your APIs act differently in Release mode you need to isolate this bug and see which line is causing the problem.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith Image circle nuget is working fine in debug mode, but when moved to release mode it is not working. All the pictures are showing in square format, what is the possible issue with this?

Comment: Try checking out the issues in the github or the docs maybe there is some initialization of the package you're missing.

Comment: @SreejithSree normally this is not happens ,  but you should check for error which line of code causing this can you try cleaning you solution and delete you obj and bin folder then rebuild solution, this is because debug is run without native tool chain, but release mode is run it with native tool chain check it in properties

Comment: @AbsoluteSith What about pushing the windows app in debug mode? Is there any problem when pushing the windows app in debug mode?

Comment: @SreejithSree: You can't do that. They'll reject it. Don't try any shortcuts they never work. Just fix the issue or try alternate options.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith I refer the following youtube video for uploading windows app to windows store. They use debug mode for uploading. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ls6hoMa2Ho

Comment: @SreejithSree You can not upload your debug mode package to store as @ AbsoluteSith's comment.The video you linked still use the release mode  package, see the vedio in the time **2:52**, the **Solution Configuration** is **Release**, it create a **Release** package to upload. You should fix your issue firstly then create Release package to upload to store.

Comment: @ShubhamSahu deleting the bin and obj folder solve the picture upload issue. And change the popup init code solved the picture popup issue.

Comment: @SreejithSree happy to help you , you can share which line of code previously produce error and what you change as answer 

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Iniially I used this code: Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

Comment: I change this code by following code: Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For closing the question or for marked as answered i am posting a formal answer:

1) Uploadable package should be of Release version.

2) Before uploading package to the store it should be tested in release mode also.

3) Because Release version of package build with native tool chain and optimized code so result may be different in debug and release mode.

4) If every thing looks correct in code, but error still occurs, try to clean solution and empty obj and bin folder

5) Also check output windows in release mode or check for which line of code producing error.

Answer (score 0):

**Updating the complete solution:**

For me, 3 features are not working in release mode. They are:

1. The circle picture is not working, all pictures are in square format.
2. The picture upload is not working.
3. The image popup is not working

**Solutions**

1. Clean, rebuild and deleting bin and obj folders solved the uploading picture issue.
2. Solved the picture pop up issue by changing the init code of rg plugins pop up like below.

   ```
   Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();

   Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
   ```

**Changing the above code by following code:**

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());
```

3. Solved tyhe circle image issue by following code:

```
   var rendererAssemblies = new[]
    {
        typeof(ImageCircleRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
    };
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, rendererAssemblies);
```

**But not possible to call Xamarin.Forms.Init twice with different assemblies. So I merge both init codes like below.**

```
var rendererAssemblies = new List<Assembly>
{
    typeof(ImageCircleRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
};
rendererAssemblies.AddRange(Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, rendererAssemblies);
```